# JS - jQuery inarray ignoreCase() and contains()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, contains, case-insensitive

well, I am more of a PHP person, and my JS skills are close to none when it comes to any JS other than simple design related operations , so excuse me if I am asking the obvious .

the following operations would be a breeze in PHP (and might also be in JS - but I am fighting with unfamiliar syntax here ...)

It is some sort of input validation

```
var ar = ["BRS201103-0783-CT-S", "MAGIC WORD", "magic", "Words", "Magic-Word"];

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("form#searchreport").submit(function() {
        if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val(), ar) != -1){ 
                jQuery("#contentresults").delay(800).show("slow");

            return false;
          }
```

This question has 2 parts .

- 1 - how can I make it possible for the array to be case insensitive ?

E.g. - `BRS201103-0783-CT-S` will give the same result as `brs201103-0783-ct-s` AND `Brs201103-0783-CT-s` or `MAGIC magic Magic MaGIc`

basically i need something like ignoreCase() for array , but I could not find any reference to that in jQuery nor JS...

I tried `toLowerCase()` - but It is not working on the array (ittirating??) and also, would it resolve the mixed case ?

- 2 - How can I make the function to recognize only parts or
  combinations of the elements ?

E.g. - if one types only `"word"` , I would like it to pass as `"words"` , and also if someone types `"some word"` it should pass (containing "word" )

Comment: For 1, I'd just type your JS array in lowecase then call `if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val().toLowerCase(), ar) != -1){`, the second part of the questions seems a little too broad. What are the specific rules? `word` is contained in `words` ok, but `some word` is not contained in `words`.

Comment: thanks for the comment , what I meant is `some word` contains `word` and also `words` contains `word`(part of string...)

Comment: Ok, strangest thing . putting `val().toLowerCase()` will work on a word like "magic/MAgIc" - but now it returns false the string `BRS201103-0783-CT-S` no matter how I enter it (small case letters , upper case  or mixed..

Comment: Most likely because `magic` is lowercase in your array, while `BRS201103-0783-CT-S` is not. Check alex's answer, he posted a simple function to pass your whole array to lowercase. `:)`

Comment: Ok, I am checking it now, but only for understanding better , if my array will be all lower case , than every input case will pass ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Part 1

You can process your array to be entirely lowercase, and lowercase your input so `indexOf()` will work like it's performing a case insensitive search.

You can lowercase a string with `toLowerCase()` as you've already figured out.

To do an array, you can use...

```
arr = arr.map(function(elem) { return elem.toLowerCase(); });
```

#### Part 2

You could check for a substring, for example...

```
// Assuming you've already transformed the input and array to lowercase.
var input = "word";
var words = ["word", "words", "wordly", "not"];

var found = words.some(function(elem) { return elem.indexOf(input) != -1; });
```

Alternatively, you could skip in this instance transforming the array to be all lowercase by calling `toLowerCase()` on each `elem` before you check `indexOf()`.

[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) aren't supported in older IEs, but are trivial to polyfill. An example of a polyfill for each is available at the linked documentation.

As [Fabrício Matté](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331430/fabricio-matte) also pointed out, you can use the jQuery equivalents here, `$.map()` for `Array.prototype.map()` and `$.grep()` with `length` property for `Array.prototype.some()`. Then you will get the browser compatibility for free.

Comment: As OP has experience with PHP, may as well add that JS's [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) works similarly to PHP's [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), except that `indexOf` returns `-1` for no match instead of `false` as PHP does and the syntax/parameters is slightly different.

Comment: @alex . Thanks . as much as your answer seems logic , the 1st part is not working for me somehow (maybe I am applying it wrong ??) - It returns true on lower but still false on upper .. I had put it like a new VAR `var arr = ar.map(function(elem) { return elem.toLowerCase(); });` and then `if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery("input:first").val(), arr) != -1)`  (Note that my original array was called "ar" and not "arr" . is the culprit there ?

Comment: You still need to call `toLowerCase()` on the input's `value`, e.g. `jQuery("input:first").val().toLowerCase()`.

Comment: .. stupid little me . I had it there from @Fabrício Matté reply, and then deleted . Thanks , all works just great . and more importantly - I have actually learned something :-) (to double check the code of masters before saying it is not working :-)  )

Comment: I'll +1 as well, I didn't know that [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is implemented in JS 1.6. Using jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) would provide compatibility with IE6-8 which the native JS `.map` doesn't.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Good point, just be careful with jQuery's `map()`, it does things differently (like flattening returned arrays).

Comment: In that case, the `.map` may also be added to the array prototype if it's not natively supported, as shown in the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility). `=]`

Answer (score 1):

To check if an array contains an element, case-insensitive, I used this code:

```
    ret = $.grep( array, function (n,i) {
        return ( n && n.toLowerCase().indexOf(elem.toLowerCase())!=-1 );
    }) ;
```

Here is a fiddle to play with
[array match case insensitive](https://jsfiddle.net/jmgomez/rdcwvhze/)